Complex Analytic 1-1 functions
Statement : If $f$ is analytic at $z_{0}$ and $f^{\prime}\left(z_{0}\right) \neq 0$, then there is an open disk $D$ centered at $z_{0}$ such that $f$ is one-to-one on $D$.
The first couple of arguments in the proof appeared in Saff's book is as follows.

Since $f^{\prime}$ is also analytic at $z_{0}$ and $\left|f^{\prime}\left(z_{0}\right)\right|>0$, there is an open disk $D$ centered at $z_{0}$ such that $\left|f^{\prime}(z)-f^{\prime}\left(z_{0}\right)\right| \leq\left|f^{\prime}\left(z_{0}\right)\right| / 2$ for all $z$ in $D$.

We shall show that, $\left|f\left(z_{1}\right)-f\left(z_{2}\right)\right| \geq\left|z_{1}-z_{2}\right|\left|f^{\prime}\left(z_{0}\right) / 2\right|$ for $z_{1}, z_{2}$ inside this disk; so $f$ is one-to-one in $D$.


I'm finding it difficult to understand the second inequality of the 1st sentence and the 2nd sentence. Any help is much appreciated.

Since $f$ is analytic, $f'$ is continuous. In particular,  it is continuous at $z_0$, and therefore $\lim_{z\to z_0}f'(z)-f'(z_0)=0$. So, since $\frac{|f'(z_0)|}2>0$, there is some open disk $D$ centered at $z_0$ such that, if $z\in D$, $\left|f'(z)-f'(z_0)\right|\leqslant\frac{|f'(z_0)|}2$.
Concerning the second sentence, if it is indeed true that you always have, when $z_1,z_2\in D$,$$|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|\geqslant|z_1-z_2|\frac{|f'(z_0)|}2,$$then, if $z_1\ne z_2$, $|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|$ is the product of two numbers different from $0$, and therefore $f(z_1)-f(z_2)\ne0$. In other words, $f(z_1)\ne f(z_2)$.

Thank you very much for the clear explanation.

I'm glad I could help.
